# How to make Chart.js Bubble chart with ng2-chart?

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

Chart.js [supports bubble charts](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/docs/08-Bubble-Chart.md), but the [ng2-chart](http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/) docs don't mention them. Is it possible to build a bubble chart with `ng2-charts`? Any pointer to a working example would be great.

note: [cross-posted on github](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/270)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a look at [the source code](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/blob/development/components/charts/charts.ts). As of version `1.1.0` (May 17 2016), bubble charts do not appear to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

The npm package [`ng2-charts`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-charts) now supports bubble charts (as of version `2.0.0-beta.10`)

Here's the snippet from the demo app:

```html
<div style="display: block">
  <canvas baseChart [datasets]="bubbleChartData" [options]="bubbleChartOptions" [colors]="bubbleChartColors"
    [legend]="bubbleChartLegend" [chartType]="bubbleChartType"></canvas>
</div>
```

Code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartOptions, ChartType, ChartDataSets } from 'chart.js';
import { Color } from 'ng2-charts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bubble-chart',
  templateUrl: './bubble-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bubble-chart.component.scss']
})
export class BubbleChartComponent implements OnInit {
  public bubbleChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{ ticks: { min: 0, max: 30, } }],
      yAxes: [{ ticks: { min: 0, max: 30, } }]
    }
  };
  public bubbleChartType: ChartType = 'bubble';
  public bubbleChartLegend = true;

  public bubbleChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    {
      data: [
        { x: 10, y: 10, r: 10 },
        { x: 15, y: 5, r: 15 },
        { x: 26, y: 12, r: 23 },
        { x: 7, y: 8, r: 8 },
      ],
      label: 'Series A',
    },
  ];

  public bubbleChartColors: Color[] = [
    {
      backgroundColor: [
        'red',
        'green',
        'blue',
        'purple',
      ]
    }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

(I am a collaborator on that package).