# Hide one of three tooltip in ng2-charts

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, ng2-charts

I am using bubble chart referred [from](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/790)
. I am providing three values for chart data. One is `x` , another is `y` and last is `r` for radius. All three are displaying in tooltip, I want only x and y to be displayed in tooltip.

**HTML**

```
<div style="display: block" *ngIf="ChartData">
<canvas baseChart  width="400" height="180" [datasets]="ChartData" [labels]="ChartLabels" [options]="ChartOptions" [legend]="ChartLegend"
[chartType]="ChartType" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
    public ChartOptions:any = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true
  };
  public ChartLegend:boolean = true;
  public ChartType:string = 'bubble';
  public ChartData:any[] = [
    {
      data:[
        {x:15,y:15.59,r:7.5},
      ],
      label:'Series A',
      backgroundColor:'#FF6384',
      hoverBackgroundColor:'#FF6388'},
}]
}

  public ChartOptions:any = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
          }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
        }
    }],

  }
  };
```

[image: My output]

I don't need 7.5 to be displayed in tooltip.

Comment: which version are you using? [bubble charts are not supported anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37848632/11065438) and [GitHub Source](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/tree/development/demo/src/app/components/charts).

Comment: Also, try adding a StackBlitz with your code and libraries. thanks!

Comment: i look reference from [here](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/790)

Comment: yes, i figured out the same. I also saw your comment there. but its an old issue and now closed. support is now removed for bubble charts and I was wondering if you are using an older version of `ng2-charts`? If yes, please specify the version so I can look into the source of the older versions.

Comment: I am using `ng2-charts: 1.6.0`

Comment: Hey, so as i mentioned before, the library has removed support for bubble charts. however, it uses `chart.js` underneath - and I was able to find another similar library that uses `chart.js`: [angular2-chartjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-chartjs). Use it at your own risk because I am not sure if it is being maintained actively.
So, for the sake of your solution, I am putting an answer that does exactly what you need using the library I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Using [angular2-chartjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-chartjs), as `ng2-charts` no longer supports bubble charts.

[StackBlitz Editor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eavlz2)

[Working Demo](https://angular-eavlz2.stackblitz.io)